# UTF8 not working in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel

in my .net code i'm using

```
byte[] bytesToSend = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(partialtorender);
```

then m writin it to excel

the text in "Hindi" Language is coming gibberish in generated excel, can you please suggest what to do?

```
System.IO.MemoryStream memStr = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

memStr.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

 memStr.Position = 0;

FileStreamResult result1 = new FileStreamResult(memStr, "application/ms-excel");

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "newExcelSheet" + ".xls");

return result1;
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you're writing it in Excel, or whether you're telling Excel that it's UTF-8 data in any way, shape or form...

Comment: Can you please show more of your code? The line you posted only converts your UTF-8 string into a byte array. No problem there :-)

Comment: What's this `partialtorender` variable? HTML, CSV, ...?

Comment: @msirwani, yes I understand that it is a string variable. But what is it contents? You realize that `xls` files are binary files with proprietary format. In order to generate an xls file you might need to use Office Interop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try emitting an UTF-8 preamble to indicate the correct encoding to Excel. Also .xls is a proprietary binary format. You cannot just use a string variable as in your code.

Here's an example with a CSV file export:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var csv = "मानक हिन्दी;some other value";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = false,
        FileName = "newExcelSheet.csv"
    };
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(data, "text/csv");
}
```

Comment: With some minor fixes in code, It worked like a charm.
Thanks Dimitrov

Comment: Do you also have the problem that opening & saving this csv with Excel converts the csv to space delimited instead of ';' delimited?

Comment: thank you, also works when opening csv (utf8) containing kazakh symbols in excel (with default encoding 1251)

encode kz1048 not supportd in dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that the default encoding for XLS files is **not** UTF-8. Please save the file you got and open it according to this post: [Choose an encoding standard when you open a file](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-HA010121249.aspx#BM2)
Does this fix your problem?

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I have tried doing this before.
I am using Ms Office 2010... Does that create an issue??

Comment: The main problem is, that you do not show the code that generates the xls content. Do you create a xls file using the interop assemblies? And if so - why don't you create an xlsx file?

Comment: As Darin Dimitrov already asked: How is the content generated? How do you create the string that is supposed to be an Excel sheet in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution after a lot of struggle.
If you look at the text of the xls file you will see it's not a well formed html, anyway excel does handle it.
But I thought i should let excel know it's utf-8. so i used:

```
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/>");
```

before writing the rest of the stream, and it does work!.